# Selenium Web driver- How to Handle the Dynamics Table and Click Specific Element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm new in Selenium webdriver and learning the Dynamics table as the moment im stuck at point. i want to click particular company name in dynamics table i have written sample scripts for it please let me whats wrong with it.

1. im using icicidirect website.
2. Selecting the Market link from main menu bar
3. Now at the bottom of the page their is one link "Daily Share Prices" link (its below the "Top Losers" section will get it by using ctrl+f)
4. At Daily Share Prices in first column (Security Name) i.e.ABB link element is their 
   and i want to click that element

```js
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://www.icicidirect.com");
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Markets')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Daily Share Prices')]")).click();
        

        Thread.sleep(3000);
        TablePageObject tablePageObject = PageFactory.initElements(driver, TablePageObject.class);

        tablePageObject.clickLink("ABB");
        
    }


 }
```

```js
public class TablePageObject {

  private WebDriver driver;

  @
  FindBy(css = "table tr")
  private List < WebElement > allTableRows; // find all the rows of the table

  public TablePageObject(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public void clickLink(String SecurityName) {
    for (WebElement row: allTableRows) {
      List < WebElement > links = row.findElements(By.linkText("ABB"));
      // the first link by row is the company name, the second is link to be clicked
      if (links.get(0).getText().contains(SecurityName)) {
        links.get(0).click();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several suggestions:

1. You may use the following link in order to receive the required table directly

   driver.get("http://content.icicidirect.com/newsiteContent/Market/MarketStats.asp?stats=DailySharePrices");
2. You may wait for the table loading
3. Then you will found the element and click it (like in your code).

This is code that works for me

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
try{
      driver.get("http://content.icicidirect.com/newsiteContent/Market/MarketStats.asp?stats=DailySharePrices");
      (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10/*sec*/)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.linkText("ABB")));

      List<WebElement> dailyList = driver.findElements(By.linkText("ABB"));
      if (dailyList.size()!=0) {
                dailyList.get(0).click();
            }
}
catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();  
}   
finally{
       driver.close();
}
```

4. If you need find some element that not located on the first page you may extend this solution to click on the Next>> link and back to this loop improving it by removing hard coded "ABB" element.